# Is it possible for a datalist to have scrolldown?

Tags: html, html-datalist

I'm new to HTML and trying to use a `datalist`. I need to limit it to display only 5 items and the rest to be viewed using scrolldown. Is there any way?

My code :

```
<form>
    <input list="Android" name="Android">

    <datalist id="Android">
        <option value="Alpha">
        <option value="Beta">
        <option value="Cupcake">
        <option value="Doughnut">
        <option value="Eclairs">
        <option value="Fryo">
        <option value="GingerBread">
        <option value="HoneyComb">
        <option value="Icecream Sandwich">
        <option value="Jelly Bean">
        <option value="Kitkat">
        <option value="Lollipop">
        <option value="Marshmallow">
        <option value="Nougat">
    </datalist>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This is the output of my code

[image: This is the output of my code]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mind adding some code to illustrate what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's not possible to do, the `datalist` layout is defined by the browser the same as it does with the `select` tag and there is very little flexibility on customization. Your example comes from **Chrome**; in **Firefox**, it shows only 6 items and on **Edge** it shows something similar with limited size as well.

The proposed solution is using something else rather that using `datalist`, if you can't live with the `datalist` design **Chrome** offers, try some other component with a similar behavior, like `dropdown select`, `autocomplete`, `autosugest`, `typeahead`, etc.